# How to prevent UIKeyboard from dismissing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have an accessory view on my keyboard that uses a next and previous button to hop between UITextFields. When the next or previous button is pressed, an IBAction is called which finds the textfield to switch to and then performs

```
[nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Usually this works fine but once in a while the keyboard drops partially and then comes back up. I'm sure this is because becoming first responder dismisses the keyboard and then summons it back up again, and sometimes this happens slowly enough that the keyboard has visually begun dismissing before it is called back.

So how can I stop the keyboard from trying to dismiss?

Comment: I haven't seen this happening ever. posting code will be helpful

Comment: Ditto - it never fails to work. Check delegates to be sure you are not sending resigningFirstResponder in some delegate (search for it). Also, you can add a test before sending becomeFirstResponder to see if anys issues - send "canBecomeFirstResponder" and if you get no you have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard should only dismiss if you've explicitly called for it to dismiss (when you're in the same view). Just ensure there aren't any subsequent calls to: 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

Another option is to conform to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol and implement these methods:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

The latter is where you'll want to NOT call your keyboard resigner

Comment: You guys were right, I did have a resignFirstResponder call hiding in a sneaky place...